# jQuery: difference between "$(variable_name)" and "variable_name"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can you explain me what is difference between

```
var details_container = $(this).closest('.details');   
$(details_container).find('.items').slideToggle();
```

and

```
var details_container = $(this).closest('.details');  
details_container.find('.items').slideToggle();
```

I tried with jQuery 1.11 and both runs correctly. I thought that second solution was the most correct, because object is already instantiated in the variable but trying the first one I noted that browser console does not return any error and everything continue to run correctly.

Can you give more details? Maybe jQuery is smart enough to "understand" that in this case `$(details_container)` is almost equal to `details_container` ?

Comment: IMO good practise is to use ```$``` as a prefix of jQuery objects, so ```$details_container``` would indicate that the variable is a jQuery object already and that it is not needed to create a jQuery object of it again. So ```$(details_container)``` is not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/)

> When a jQuery object is passed to the `$()` function, a clone of the object is created. This new jQuery object references the same DOM elements as the initial one.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, I would like to say that `$(someDOMElement)`i, [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence):

```
$(someDOMElement) = $($($( ... $(someDOMElement) ... )))
```

for any amount of times you will call it.

That's why there is the good practice to prefix cached jquery selector variables with `$`:

```
var $details_container = $(this).closest('.details');
```